# Mobile email launch + onclick event for redirect

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have the following simple text with the function of 2 things on a mobile phone:

1. open the email with a pre-populated subject and body
2. `onclick` function to redirect user to a specified URL

A similar site the does this is:
http://app.mobileoptin.com/c2926/advertlines

In this sample above, in a mobile browser, if the user clicks on the button "Click Here For Access" it will:

1. open the email mobile client with text
2. redirect user in the background to a specific URL

This is exactly what i need.

**CODE I HAVE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                function Redirect() {
                 window.location.href="http://www.google.com";   
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="mailto:test@theearth.com?subject=Circle Around&body=Some blah" name="redirect" onclick="Redirect();">Email</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works good on desktop, but by some reason I can not have it working on mobile, at least in android.

Thanks for your ideas, if there is a better way to do this, your welcome to advised.

Answer (score 0):

```
 /// add here your url link
    String url = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/apply";

    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append("hi friends please visit my website for");
    int start = builder.length();
    builder.append(url);
    int end = builder.length();

    builder.setSpan(new URLSpan(url), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      i.setType("message/rfc822");
      i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"abcd@gmail.com"});
      i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email is this");
      i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, builder);
       try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
           } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, is that place where in the code? Or it's a new way to do the task?

Comment: this is for onClick event of any thing like Button or textview.. you can open Mail using above code in android

Comment: nono, i want to do the function in a web browser, look this: http://app.mobileoptin.com/c3452/trip . click on the red button on a mobile, you will see what i need :)